# Categorical scatter plot with mean segments using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a simple scatter plot for 3 groups, overlaying a segment indicating the mean for each group and labelling the groups. 
I have managed to get a scatter plot with error bars, but I would only like a segment indicating where the mean is. I also cannot seem to be getting the group labelling right.

To get the summary statistics I am using the function "summarySE" from [this page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_%28ggplot2%29/). [EDIT: note this function is also provided in the Rmisc package]

Is there any simpler way to do this, and to get a segment instead of a point for the mean?

I really appreciate your help!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame(tt = rep(1:3, each = 40),
       val = round(rnorm(120, m = rep(c(4, 5, 7), each = 40))))

# After loading the summarySE function:

dfc <- summarySE(df, measurevar="val", groupvars="tt")


ggplot(dfc, aes(tt, val), main="Scatter plot with mean bars", 
      xlab="Groups", ylab="Values", names=c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"))+
  geom_jitter(aes(tt, val), data = df, colour = I("red"), 
               position = position_jitter(width = 0.05)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=val-sd, ymax=val+sd), width = 0.01, size = 1)
```

Comment: +1! It is better to avoid linking many extra functions, and just add some sample of your data (df and dfc), don't forget also to set `set.seed` to make your example completely reproducible.

Comment: thank you for the tip! I'll know that for next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `geom_crossbar()` and use `val` as `y`, `ymin` and `ymax` values. With `scale_x_continuous()` you can change x axis labels for original data or use @agstudy solution to change original data and labels will appear automatically.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_jitter(aes(tt, val), data = df, colour = I("red"), 
              position = position_jitter(width = 0.05)) +
  geom_crossbar(data=dfc,aes(x=tt,ymin=val, ymax=val,y=val,group=tt), width = 0.5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3),labels=c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Sorry about the code for summarySE, it is here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 1):

To get the group labelling , You can change continuous tt a factor like this :

```
dfc$tt <- factor(dfc$tt,labels=c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"))
```

Of course before calling `summarySE` and creating `dfc`.

and using `crossbar` as mentioned in the other solution below , you get:

[image]