# How to make categorical scatterplot in R with median marking

Tags: r, ggplot2, categories, scatter-plot, categorical-data

My data are set up so that one column contains a continuous value testosterone concentration and the second column contains one of four "Kit type" values being "EIA," "RIA," "Other," or "All." I wanted to make the kit types into categories along the x axis with testosterone concentration along the y. I can't seem to figure out how to make sort of a cross between a boxplot and a scatterplot, but with only the individual data points and a median marking for each category marked on the graph?

This seemed to get me the data points into catagories alright, but the summarySE function does not have a median: [Categorical scatter plot with mean segments using ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807774/categorical-scatter-plot-with-mean-segments-using-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: melle1223, if the answer met your needs, it is customary to "accept" and answer, both to thank the volunteers, and to mark the question as resolved for anybody who reads your question in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Without data, I'm only guessing here, but ...

```
## create some data
set.seed(42)
n <- 100
dat <- data.frame(Testo=rbeta(n, 2, 5),
                  Kit=sample(c('EIA', 'RIA', 'Other', 'All'), size = n, replace = TRUE))

## show unequal distribution of points, no problem
table(dat$Kit)
##   All   EIA Other   RIA 
##    23    30    14    33 

## break into individual levels
dat2 <- lapply(levels(dat$Kit), function(lvl) dat$Testo[ dat$Kit == lvl ])
names(dat2) <- levels(dat$Kit)

## parent plot
boxplot(dat2, main = 'Testosterone Levels per Kit')

## adding individual points
for (lvl in seq_along(dat2)) {
    points(jitter(rep(lvl, length(dat2[[lvl]]))), dat2[[lvl]],
           pch = 16, col = '#88888888')
}
```

[image: Faceted box/scatterplot of random levels.]

Comment: Very cool answer. I would suggest adding `outline=F` in the arguments to `boxplot`, otherwise the higher outliers are represented twice (see for example the high outlier in the leftmost group)