# R - box and scatterplot from dataframe containing categorical variable

Tags: python, r, plot, ggplot2, seaborn

I'm trying to create a grouped scatter plot which looks like this (with addition of different categories for each group): 
[image]

while I can make something equivalent using seaborn which can handle categorical variables too(https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_categorical.html), I'm not sure how can I represent categorical variables in ggplot2. This is somewhat similar to previous question ([How to add 4 groups to make Categorical scatter plot with mean segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713614/how-to-add-4-groups-to-make-categorical-scatter-plot-with-mean-segments)) but each groups has categories too in my case. This is how my data looks in wide form (with columns as groups and last column describing the category for rows):

```
    BL_CA_1 BL_CA_2 BL_CA_3 CA_BL_1 CA_BL_2 CA_BL_3 BL6_1   BL6_2   BL6_3   CA_1    CA_2    CA_3    Catagory    
BL6_0   -0.656576   -0.930668   -0.56313    -0.798757   -1.28959    -0.99541    -0.154347   0.0172292   -0.0737639  -0.851593   -1.20257    -1.14919    mono:plus   
BL6_1   3.57263 3.49639 3.4982  3.66428 3.72131 3.72738 4.30273 4.2434  4.34975 2.93424 2.91043 2.93532 mono:minus  
BL6_2   5.20641 5.07323 5.05197 5.21741 5.24606 5.23684 5.40763 5.37346 5.43318 5.02805 5.00924 4.91372 mono:plus   
BL6_3   5.20645 5.32332 5.36965 5.19996 5.1646  5.17797 6.26934 6.30538 6.29584 -2.17544    -1.70483    -1.77652    mono:minus  
CAST_1  3.4924  3.57383 3.6345  3.66375 3.65961 3.72133 5.02467 5.27127 5.2847  0.226526    0.0656529   0.363539    mono:plus   
CAST_2  2.06141 2.13846 2.0506  2.02542 2.09087 2.1134  2.50185 2.58112 2.48791 1.57613 1.70318 1.67168 mono:plus   
CAST_3  -11.5074    -12.2199    -10.9278    -11.135 -11.63  -1.51775    -1.12501    -12.1658    -11.6888    -12.3539    -12.0911    -12.5457    bi:plus-minus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)
d %>%
  as.tibble() %>% 
  gather(k, v, -Catagory) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(k, v)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_beeswarm() + 
    facet_grid(~Catagory) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly!  I realized that separating categories on subgraphs rather than using colors is way way better. Thank you.