# Plot one vs many actual-predicted values scatter plot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter

For a sample dataframe `df`, `pred_value` and `real_value` respectively represent the monthly predicted values and actual values for a variable, and `acc_level` represents the accuracy level of the predicted values comparing with the actual values for the correspondent month, the smaller the values are, more accurate the predictions result:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2022/3/31", "2022/4/30", 
"2022/5/31"), class = "factor"), pred_value = c(2721.8, 2721.8, 
2705.5, 2500, 2900.05, 2795.66, 2694.45, 2855.36, 2300, 2799.82, 
2307.36, 2810.71, 3032.91), real_value = c(2736.2, 2736.2, 2736.2, 
2736.2, 2736.2, 2759.98, 2759.98, 2759.98, 2759.98, 3000, 3000, 
3000, 3000), acc_level = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L
))
```

Out:

```
        date pred_value real_value acc_level
1  2022/3/31    2721.80    2736.20         1
2  2022/3/31    2721.80    2736.20         1
3  2022/3/31    2705.50    2736.20         2
4  2022/3/31    2500.00    2736.20         3
5  2022/3/31    2900.05    2736.20         3
6  2022/4/30    2795.66    2759.98         1
7  2022/4/30    2694.45    2759.98         2
8  2022/4/30    2855.36    2759.98         2
9  2022/4/30    2300.00    2759.98         3
10 2022/5/31    2799.82    3000.00         2
11 2022/5/31    2307.36    3000.00         3
12 2022/5/31    2810.71    3000.00         2
13 2022/5/31    3032.91    3000.00         1
```

I've plotted the predicted values with code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(x=date, y=pred_value, color=acc_level)) +
  geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.7, position=position_jitter(w=0.1, h=0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Out:

[image]

Beyond what I've done above, if I hope to plot the actual values for each month with red line and red points, how could I do that? Thanks.

**Reference:**

[How to add 4 groups to make Categorical scatter plot with mean segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713614/how-to-add-4-groups-to-make-categorical-scatter-plot-with-mean-segments)

Comment: `geom_point(size=2, aes(y = real_value), color = "red") +
  geom_line(size=2, aes(y = real_value, group = 1), color = "red") +`  (The `group` parameter tells the line layer the points are grouped together even though their underlying rows have different acc_level. You could alternately put the `acc_level` mapping in the aes of your `pred_value` layer so it doesn't meddle with the default colors and grouping of other layers.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again, your solution seems helping me almost get what I need, also I'm considering convert `acc_level` as factor then use `scale_color_manual(values = my_colors); my_colors <- c("yellow", "magenta", "cyan")`. If you don't mind, please post your code as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the actuals using additional layers. To make the line show up, we need to specify that the points should be part of the same series.

ggplot assumes by default that since the x axis is discrete that the data points are not part of the same group. We could alternatively  deal with this by making the `date` variable into a date data type, like with `aes(x=as.Date(date)...`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=pred_value, color=as.factor(acc_level))) +
  geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.7, position=position_jitter(w=0.1, h=0)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = real_value), size=2, color = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = real_value, group = 1), color = "red") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow", "magenta", "cyan"),
                     name = "Acc Level") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your detailed explanation and perfect code. One more question, let's say actual `df` is for one variable `x1`, if I have one more column `variable` in `df` for indicating multiple variables. If I want to produce one plot like your output for each variable then save them (ie., for `x1`, we will save it by `ggsave("./x1.png")`). To do so, should I convert your code to a function  then use for loop?

Comment: A common way to do that in ggplot is by reshaping the data long (eg with `tidyr::pivot_longer`) and then putting those on facets. But if you want separate files then yes, a function in a loop. Lots of solutions on SO for that workflow.